# Is there a function or code which can number the candlestick of a timeframe? For example: 4H = candle 1,2,3,4

Tags: function, indicator

I am looking for a peice of code, a function or an indicator that can number the candlesticks of any trading timeframe. If anyone can help with this it would be greatly apprecited. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too openended but maybe you could do something like this

https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/recognizing-over-50-candlestick-patterns-with-python-4f02a1822cb5